# I am getting this axios error after cloning project from gihtub. I have done all the set up properly. AxiosError

Tags: axios, mern

I have cloned github project from github.
I did set the proxy to : `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
My backend server is running on port 5000 properly and when I make a request using postman. For example :
`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/all-users`, I get proper data in the postman but when I make request from frontend For Example : POST `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/register` is gives following error :
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' ....}

What could be the reason for this? How can I solve this error?

I tried changing localhost to `127.0.0.1` and reverse but nothing worked for me.